# Display image of 2D Sinewaves in 3D

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I've generated a 1D sine wave and then repeated it every row to have a 2D sine wave. I can show this in 2d space, but I need to produce a 3D plot that shows the peaks and valleys as well as the oscillatory patterns between them.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
N = 256
x = np.linspace(-np.pi,np.pi, N)
sine1D = 128.0 + (127.0 * np.sin(x))
sine1D = np.uint8(sine1D)
sine2D = np.tile(sine1D, (N,1))
plt.imshow(sine2D, cmap='gray')
```

Comment: Have you browsed the [gallery for the mplot3d toolkit](https://matplotlib.org/gallery.html#mplot3d) for examples that you might be able to modify to do what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how about, as @Warren Weckesser said, use the [mplot3d toolkit examples gallery](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html), and for instance surface plot of the magnitude of a sinewave as function of time and phase:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax3d = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

# Make the X, Y meshgrid instead of np.tile
xs = np.linspace(-2*np.pi, 2*np.pi, 200)
ys = np.linspace(-2*np.pi, 2*np.pi, 200)
tau, phi = np.meshgrid(xs, ys) 
# Z evaluation
amp = np.sin(tau+phi) 

ax3d.set_xlabel(r'$\tau$')  # tau = omega*t -> adimensional time
ax3d.set_ylabel(r'$\phi$')  # phi -> phase
ax3d.set_zlabel(r'$amp$')   # signal amplitude

surf = ax3d.plot_surface(tau, phi, amp,cmap=cm.inferno)
fig.colorbar(surf)
```

that gives :

[image: 3d_sinewave_surface]

Comment: Merci for the answer. And I think it should be mentioned that $\tau$ and $\phi$ are repeated values of spatial coordinates, $x$ and $y$.