# Generate an Image of a sloped sinewave

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

How we can generate the following grayscale image in Python?

The following code generates horizontal pattern, but I need a sloped one.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 256
x = np.linspace(-np.pi,np.pi, N)
sine1D = 128.0 + (127.0 * np.sin(x * 8.0))
sine1D = np.uint8(sine1D)
sine2D = np.tile(sine1D, (N,1))
print(sine2D.shape)
plt.imshow(sine2D, cmap='gray')
```

[image]

Comment: you might want to add _numpy_ to your tags as well , there is probably a numpy shortcut to my loop below.

Comment: How about rotating it?

Comment: I would be grateful if everyone read this topic, take also a kind look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57534418

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In response to your comment below @Patrick Artner's answer:

> *As we can see numpy.roll cannot generate a smooth pattern*

The function `np.roll` is not responsible for the smoothness of the resulting image, it's the function [plt.imshow](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html). You need to tell it how to properly interpolate the generated data. So just by specifying the `interpolation` keyword argument to the function call, you may have for instance:

```
plt.imshow(sine2D,interpolation='bilinear', cmap='gray')
```

which leads to a smoother result:

[image: smooth_roll]

but there are plenty of other possibilities : `'bicubic'`, `'spline16'`, `'spline36'`...

Answer (score 3):

You can use [numpy.roll](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html) to shift your 1D sine data around:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 256
x = np.linspace(-np.pi,np.pi, N)
sine1D = 128.0 + (127.0 * np.sin(x * 8.0))
sine1D = np.uint8(sine1D)
sine2D = np.ndarray((N,N), dtype=np.uint8)
for i in range(N):
    sine2D[i]= np.roll(sine1D,-i)  # shift the 1D sin data by -i, -i increases with rows
plt.imshow(sine2D, cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image: resulting image]

If you roll your 1D data you'll get the desired slanted pattern. If you want a special slanted angle you would have to roll more/less then 1 per advacing row to get it flatter/steeper.

Documentation:

- [numpy.roll](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As we can see numpy.roll cannot generate a smooth pattern. I think if we can combine two 1d sinewaves, one in x-direction and another in the y-direction, i.e. something like `sin((x + y) * 8.0)`, we reach to a smooth graph. However, I'm not able to implement this idea yet.